# Securing Kafka topic in hyperledger fabric

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a question related to securing kafka topic on hyperledger fabric my question is as follows

1. I have a hyperledger network with 1 orderer and kafka cluster set up
2. My orderer is subscribed to the kafka topic and gets the blocks from kafka
3. Now what if any other node (external node or node other than orderer)  subscribes to kakfa and fetches data
4. How can we secure kafka topics to be limited to hyperledger orderer service nodes and ensure that kafka only connects to OSN(Ordering service node) and not any external nodes
5. Is orderer MSP involved or used when orderer subscribes to a kafka topic

Comment: Have you already resolved this?

Comment: @NitishBhardwaj no not resolved yet

Answer (score 2):

I got this reference from Hyperledger Community:

> You can use mutual TLS between the orderer nodes and the Kafka
>   brokers. You'll need to follow the Kafka documentation on setting up
>   client authentication with mutual TLS. For each orderer node, you can
>   specify the PrivateKey and Certificate to use to communicate with the
>   Kafka brokers. You can find these settings in orderer.yaml under the
>   Kafka section.

Please visit this link for more details:
https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/23037291

Hope this helps.